# In .NET, why doesn't pointing to a data source implicitly bind the data?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datasource

Consider the following code:

```
var setData = database.sets.Where(x => x.Value > 2);
uxSetDataGrid.DataSource = setList.ToList();
uxSetDataGrid.DataBind();
```

I'm curious why the second line of code doesn't automatically do a DataBind() on the control. If it knows the data source, why not bind in the same step? It could save some lines of code and keystrokes. Perhaps I'm missing context since I'm a pretty new .NET developer, but are there any situations where you wouldn't want to do DataBind() immediately after pointing to a DataSource?

Comment: What if I don't _want_ to?

Comment: The other answer is, you're new to this. It's too early for you to speculate. Just  know that _you_ may not have reasons for doing the two separately, but those of us with far more experience than you, just  might. We're wiser that way.

Comment: I acknowledged that I may not have reasons for doing the two separately and that those with more experience might. What I want to know, though, is when and why you might want to do the two separately.

Comment: *somewhat related*,  usually you need `DataBind` with ASP.Net, in `winform`, there is no `DataBind`

Comment: @Will what was the rationale for that decision? Or, barring that, when would someone want to do the two separately?

Comment: I don't know what Will is saying, but I'm saying the answer is well over your paygrade. Don't worry about it. You have many other things to worry about. Some of them actually matter.

Comment: @HandleThatError I was under the impression that you didn't need to use `DataBind()` when invoking `.ToList()` on your dataset since that actually makes the set non-lazy?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand that it is over my paygrade, but I'm curious as to the reasoning. It's something I want to know out of curiosity, not out of necessity. Is that so wrong? Is there an answer? Was the distinction between datasource and databind arbitrary? Is that the joke here? It must be the joke, because people on stackoverflow are typically very friendly when it comes to sharing knowledge. Whereas right now it seems a few people are more interested in trolling rather than sharing knowledge.

Comment: One little hint. `DataBind` is a method on the `Control` class. It raises the `DataBinding` event on the control. `DataBinding` is the event where data binding expressions are evaluated.

Comment: Among other things you would be overlooking right now if you even _knew_ about them, take a look at `DataSourceId`.

Comment: @EricHerlitz No, you still need to use DataBind() even after using ToList(). I just tried the code without the DataBind() and it didn't populate my control with any data.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the input, I will look into DataSourceId and the Control class. And also the DataBinding event. Thanks for pointing me in a direction, it's better than being told that the knowledge is above my paygrade.

Comment: It's just not very useful at this stage. It will be  useful somewhat later, just not right now. I hate to see someone going off on a tangent learning how things work before they know how to use them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can understand that, but then again when will someone in my shoes learn when to learn about something? I suppose sometimes curiosity should be rewarded with knowledge, even if we can't make the most of the knowledge until a later date. I'd rather know that there ARE some uses to having databind and datasource as separate things, even if many details will have to be "magic" until a later date. Do pardon me for being curious, but I reckon that asking questions is always good even if you can't use the answers right away. After all, knowing what you just said helps in itself. ;)

Comment: I guess I'm being a bit paternal, trying to keep you from the mistakes that _I_ made - so that you'll make _different_ mistakes. I found I did best at learning "what's beneath" either 1) when I got bored with dealing with what's on the surface because I knew it well already, or 2) when I _needed_ to know. I learned about the `DataBinding` event when I needed to see what the code generated by ASP.NET actually _did_ on a DataBind that wasn't working correctly with a complex custom control. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand and I appreciate that, actually. Can I refer to you as my Code Dad? :) Being that I don't need to know the details about databind and datasource at this point in time, I'll accept your advice and stick to what I need to know. Thanks!